# how to generate a url which opens my android app

Tags: android

I have a share button in my android app. If I click on it I can share anything with my contacts (Facebook, WhatsApp, messaging, share it, Bluetooth....etc). I wanted to share URL to WhatsApp through which when I click on that URL user should be directed to my app(to a particular activity).

How should I generate the URL so that it would be shared with my contacts?

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

Comment: Please try to use this startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<YOUR PACKAGE NAME>")));

Comment: I have already read this document but there is no website for my app . In third step it is asking website declaration

Comment: @FalduJaldeep would u please tell me entire procedure

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
    "Pleas check my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<YOUR APPLICATION PAGE NAME>");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Ex:

```
Button btnShare;

btnShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                shareApp();
            }
        });

   private void shareApp()
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Pleas check my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

Comment: thank you but I have a doubt "Pleas check my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp" is this website url

Comment: Instead of com.myapp you need to specify your application package name.

Comment: Yes it's playstore link